# Adding a new item into navigation property causes "Collection navigation properties must > implement ICollection<> of the target type" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following code, where I need to add a new item into the navigation property depending on the condition. `NotificationToUser` property of `Notification` class is `IEnumerable` type.

```
  Notification notification = new Notification
  {
      DateCreated = DateTime.Now,          
      ToUsers = _context.PeerGroupMemberships
         .Where(pg => pg.PeerGroup.SubmissionId == assessmentItem.SubmissionId && pg.UserId != currentUser.Id)                                       
         .Select(pg => new NotificationToUser { IsRead = false, UserId = pg.UserId })
  };


  if(submissionOwnerId != currentUser.Id)
  {
      notification.ToUsers = notification.ToUsers.Append(new NotificationToUser { IsRead = false, UserId = submissionOwnerId });
  }

  _context.Notifications.Add(notification);
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

However, adding a new item to the navigation property causes this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type of navigation property
>   'ToUsers' on the entity type 'Notification' is
>   'AppendPrepend1Iterator' which does not implement
>   ICollection. Collection navigation properties must
>   implement ICollection<> of the target type.'

The Notification class is:

```
public class Notification
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<NotificationToUser> ToUsers { get; set; }

}
```

I wonder how I can mitigate this issue.

Comment: Show the source for `Notification`.

Comment: Why did someone on this earth vote to close this question?!?!?!

Comment: @ChrisPratt I added.

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what to do. `ToUsers` needs to be an `ICollection` to be used as a navigation property, i.e. `public ICollection<NotificationToUser> To Users { get; set; }`.

Comment: is there an alternative to this solution?

Comment: No. Based on the things EF has to do to collection properties, it can't be an IEnumerable

Answer (score 9):

Since your `ToUsers` is `IEnumerable<NotificationToUser>` type, you need to use `ToList()` before you save the data.In your situation,it is `IQueryable<NotificationToUser>` after `Select`.

Modify your code as follow:

```
if(submissionOwnerId != currentUser.Id)
{
  notification.ToUsers = notification.ToUsers
                         .Append(new NotificationToUser { IsRead = false, UserId = submissionOwnerId })
                         .ToList()
}else//for the situation you do not need to append new NotificationToUser 
{
 notification.ToUsers = notification.ToUsers.ToList()
}
_context.Notifications.Add(notification);
_context.SaveChanges();
```